# How to reformat .c file from windows to UNIX?

Tags: c, windows, unix, text, formatting

I wrote a program with CodeBlocks on Windows and when I try to compile it in a Unix Terminal it shows me multiple errors and warnings. I'm almost sure it's connected to differences in text formatting differences between these two systems.

Sometimes something similar happens when you copy a code from website etc.

My question is how to reformat `.c` files to be able to compile it with `cc` command in a Unix terminal without rewriting the whole program?

Comment: *I'm almost sure it's connected to differences in text formatting differences between these two systems.* That should never be the case for C/C++ programs.

Comment: You should post some example code and the compiler errors.

Comment: When you say 'CodeBlocks' do you mean http://www.codeblocks.org/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dos2unix command: [dos2unix](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix)

Answer (score 2):

The text formatting of the source file of a C program should be irrelevant. Unless the file is encoded in such a way that the compiler itself cannot read (for example you wrote it all in Kanji instead of ASCII characters).

You have not provided either the source file, the errors when compiled under Windows, the errors, if any, when compiled under Unix or even the commands you are trying to run and the versions of the compilers. Without further information no better answer can be provided.